# I am writing a recursive function that will create bucketsaccording to n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a recursive function that will create empty buckets according to n. However my code is not working. No matter what n is it'll only print none.

Can someone help me with where I am going wrong?

for example if n is 5 it should print [[], [], [], [], []]

```
def emptyBuckets(n):
        assert n > 0
        bucket = []
        # Base case: only one empty bucket
        if n == 1:
            return bucket
        else:
            return (bucket.append(emptyBuckets(n-1))

print (emptyBuckets(5))
```

Comment: Question: do you want the result of calling `emptyBuckets(n)` to be a string, or a list of strings, or a list of empty lists?

Comment: A list of empty strings

Comment: A list of empty strings would be `['', '', '', '']`, not what you have. A list of empty lists is `[[], [], [], []]` (which you seem to show), a list of strings showing empty brackets is `['[]', '[]', '[]', '[]']`, and a single string showing all these brackets is `'[[], [], [], []]'`. Precision is important.

Comment: Sorry I was supposed to write a list of empty lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping this as similar to your code as possible to highlight a couple of things.

First, when you define something like `bucket = []`, you are saying that `bucket` is an *empty list*, not a pair of brackets. If you want to be able to print brackets, you should define `bucket` as a string.

Second, you need to enclose your recursive return in another pair of brackets, again *as a string*.

```
def emptyBrackets(n):
    assert n > 0
    bucket = '[]'  # a string representing empty brackets
    if n == 1:  # base case
        return  bucket
    else:
        return f'[{emptyBrackets(n-1)}]'  # using fancy formatted strings
```

That last line could also be `return '[{}]'.format(emptyBrackets(n-1))`, or `return '[' + emptyBrackets(n-1) + ']'`, or, as another answer suggested, you could use the `%` operator. Personal pref, but I like the one in the code block above the best.

Comment: Thanks but understood the question wrong i've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the returning value of a recursive call in a pair of brackets as a string instead:

```
def emptyBuckets(n):
    return '[%s]' % emptyBuckets(n - 1) if n else ''
```

so that `emptyBuckets(5)` returns:

```
[[[[[]]]]]
```